# Use the binomial theorem to prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^5}{3^n}=0$

Tags: real-analysis

I found an interesting exercise in my analysis book. It says to use the binomial theorem to prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^5}{3^n}=0$. Moreover I'm not allowed to use limit theorems in the proof.

This is in the context of an introduction to sequences.

I know that a ratio test would work, but that theorem is introduced 2 sections later, so it's clearly not supposed to be used here. I haven't been able to come up with a proof which involves the binomial theorem.

I have been able to prove the limit though. I proved by induction that $3^n>n^6$ for $n>15$ and that therefore $|\frac{n^5}{3^n}|<\epsilon$ for a given $\epsilon$ $>0$ if $n>\max(\frac{1}{e},15)$ and that the limit converges to $0$. In that induction proof I used the binomial theorem, yes, but I don't think it's the solution the author had in mind.

I'd like to hear your opinions? Perhaps there's something I'm not seeing?

Comment: $$3^n = (1+2)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} 2^k > \binom{n}{6}\cdot 2^6$$ for $n \geqslant 6$.

Comment: Hey Daniel, I noticed this too. But I didn't seem to find an application for this. Do I replace $3^n$ with the right hand of your equation in the limit? Does that make the limit any easier to prove? Because it doesn't seem so to me.

Comment: Yes, you replace $3^n$ with the right hand side. So you get $$0 < \frac{n^5}{3^n} < \frac{n^5\cdot 6!}{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)\cdot 2^6}$$ for $n \geqslant 6$. We can ignore the constants $6!$ and $2^6$, and then "only" need to see that $$n \biggl(1 - \frac{1}{n}\biggr)\cdot\dotsc\cdot\biggl(1 - \frac{5}{n}\biggr) \to +\infty.$$

Comment: It's not really easier, but neither is it really more difficult. I guess it's the expected argument, however.

Comment: I well understand your proof. Really appreciate it. However in your second comment I don't understand what you want to say with the last line. And the book wants you to state a formal, rigorous proof using an epsilon, such that $n>n$* implies that $|\frac{n^5}{3^n}|<\epsilon$ and I really don't see how to use your solution to find such an $n$* I suppose you could work out the product of 6 terms but that would be ridiculous.

Comment: We multiply numerator and denominator with $n^{-5}$ to get $$\frac{n^5}{n(n-1)\cdot\dotsc\cdot(n-5)} = \frac{1}{n\bigl(1-\frac{1}{n}\bigr)\cdot\dotsc\cdot\bigl(1-\frac{5}{n}\bigr)}.$$ To get an explicit $n^{\ast}$, we can further use $$\biggl(1-\frac{1}{n}\biggr)\cdot\dotsc\cdot\biggl(1-\frac{5}{n}\biggr) > \biggl(1-\frac{5}{n}\biggr)^5 \geqslant \biggl(1 - \frac{5}{6}\biggr)^5$$ for $n \geqslant 6$, so overall $$0 < \frac{n^5}{3^n} < \frac{6!\cdot 6^5}{n\cdot 2^6}.$$ If you fill in all details, it gets a bit cumbersome, but not too bad.

Comment: Easier would be to use $3^n > e^n > \frac{n^6}{6!}$ for $n > 0$, which gives $\frac{n^5}{3^n} < \frac{6!}{n}$ with almost no effort. But at the point of the exercise, the exponential function was probably not yet introduced.

Comment: No the exponential hasn't indeed been introduced. Thanks for your clarifications though!